# Efficient way to check if Columns exist in the DataReader

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

There are tables with over 50 columns, I am using following code to loop through the dataReader for column existence.

```
If HasColumn(reader, "EmpCode") Then obj.OwningOfficeID = CType(reader("EmpCode"), Int32)

Protected Function HasColumn(ByRef reader As SqlDataReader, ByVal columnName As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
        If reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName) Then
            Return Not IsDBNull(reader(columnName))
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

I am wondering if there is any better way of checking the columns in the DataReader instead of looping through the DataReader each time i bind the object property?

Comment: Please don't tag your question with high-viewed tags when they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Why don't you store all the column names in an array first, then iterate through that array to check for columns names?

Comment: Why 50x50 times? Only as many times as there are columns.

Comment: I think I used c# tag which is relevant to my question. 
If sp returns 50 columns then I will be calling this function on 50 column objects.

Comment: Off topic from original question, but why do this?  Surely better to just ensure there is no mismatch from your query to your code.

Comment: @user1263981: How is the c# tag relevant in your question?

Comment: I will be creating store procedures which are relevant to object class and don’t want to return 50 columns when only 5 or 6 are required.

Comment: @juergen d: c# doesn't have a dataReader Class?

Comment: @user1263981: It does. Do you use the C# DataReader class? **No.**

Comment: @juergend: Is there any difference b/w C# and VB.Net DataReader Class? I thought they are same just a syntax difference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @user1263981: Tags are there to categorize your question. People also see in what language your programming. SQL Server has a substring function. MySQL does too. But you should only tag with the language you are using and not for both. Otherwise it just confuses.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are difference products but C# and VB.NET both uses the same base class library. Also there are more C# developers than VB.Net. VB.NET developers should be allowed to tag their question in c# as long as both are using same classes. Sorry I am not negotiating here but it doesn’t make any sense to restrict vb.net developers to vb.net tags. It make sense not to use java tag with vb.net but when two languages are using same base class library then it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable` Method will give the DataTable of the executed query, from there you can get all the columns

```
Returns a DataTable that describes the column metadata.
```

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx

Answer (score 2):

currently I am using this extension method for this purpose

```
public static bool TryGetOrdinal(this IDataRecord dr, string column, out int ordinal)
{
    try
    {
        ordinal = dr.GetOrdinal(column);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ordinal = -1; //Just setting a value that GetOrdinal doesn't return
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so you use it as follows

```
int ordinal = 0;
if(dr.TryGetOrdinal("column",out ordinal))
    string val = dr.GetValue(ordinal).ToString();
```

My VB is not so good. Sorry couldn't convert it to VB for you. But I think you get the basic idea and can recode it in VB.